# Opening .bat file from Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, batch-file, outlook

I am trying to open a .bat file from outlook VBA. My code worked until this last week.

Here is the Code:

```
Sub Daily_batch_file(Mail As MailItem)

Call Shell("P:\my path\my bat.bat", vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

I have a rule that kicks this script off when I receive a particular email. I am getting an invalid call error but haven't been able to figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the P drive accessible? Have you tried to run it manually? Is the script triggered in Outlook?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of call .bat file from VBA, maybe you can open it using Rule from outlook. It's pretty simple.

Just create a blank rule with the specific word in the subject/body (or you can choose any condition based on your situation). And then in the Select Action window, tick the "Start Application" and then find your .bat/.exe file.

[image: Select Action]

I hope it's clear enough.

Thanks